# GCC for Linux (slitaz distribution)

Tags: linux

I am reading a document on compiling gcc for me to use. It is really (stupidly) long. I can't imagine that everyone who has to use gcc will go through all of this.

Can I just install the binaries from here: http://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/linux/devel/gcc/gcc-2.95.x/?
If yes, which file should I choose?

I use Slitaz Linux.

Comment: Having quickly searched for it, SliTaz Linux is a minimalistic distribution and those things are not really suited for developer workstation. I'd recommend you just use one of the major distributions (like Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora or OpenSuSE). Granted, it will take a lot more space, but disks are cheap these days and these have all kinds of software trivially installable which is not possible for minimalistic distribution like SliTaz).

Comment: Having searched a bit more, [this lists gcc package form SliTaz](http://pkgs.slitaz.org/stable/development.html) (the web is unfortunately half-defunct), so you should be able to just install it.

Comment: I already have got GCC 4.4.1, the problem was that I wanted an older version

Answer (score 1):

That is an old version of gcc by the looks of it. The latest that I remember is version 4.6 and yes you can just install the binaries for it.

Heres the command that should work for you:
tazpkg get-install gcc
This should grab the latest version for you.

Comment: He did. It's even part of the question title. (However, it's an obscure minimal distribution)

Comment: Wow i completely skipped over that. Thanks, it's kind of late at night here haha.

Comment: I already have version 4.XX, but I want the 2.95.3 one since it is recommended for compiling kernels.

Comment: I'm actually a kernel developer and unless you're using a very old kernel version you should be fine with the newer versions of gcc, personally for kernel compilation I use 4.4 because of some issues with 4.6 but I see no reason to use that old a version on any 2.6.x kernel anyway.

Comment: http://kerneltrap.org/node/799 >> Additional tips/FAQs: >> Does GCC 3.x work for compiling the Linux kernel?           I did face problems, so I think the only way is to use 2.95.3

Comment: This is from 2003, newer versions of gcc have no trouble compiling the kernel.

Comment: But I'm facing a problem, so I think I'll open another question concerning that

Comment: Well what version of the kernel are you trying to compile and what method are you using to compile it?

Comment: I opened a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517318/ygcc-command-not-found