# ygcc: Command not found

Tags: linux-kernel

While trying to compile the linux-2.6.36.1 kernel, I face this problem:-
make: ygcc: Command not found

On a website, I found this solution:-
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc ygcc

But it didn't work for me.

My GCC version is: 4.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check that you made sure to make menuconfig (or xconfig) it seems that some variables aren't set correctly.

Comment: lol. I just pressed "enter" many times since I thought it would automatically be a "yes". There are lots of new features, how do I automate the process?

Comment: If you do make menuconfig and then just go and hit save .config file then it should generate the default kernel compilation file with the correct variables.

Answer (score 3):

Open the .config file to see if the `CONFIG_CROSS_COMPILE` variable is set properly. From the error message, the most probable setting is

```
CONFIG_CROSS_COMPILE="y"
```

meaning that "y" is the prefix of your cross compiler. Thus, the build system would use `ygcc` instead of `gcc`. Also, it will try to find `yobjdump` instead of `objdump`.

This variable should only be set when you do want to cross compile the kernel or you have special prefixes to your gcc toolchain. Typically, it should be something like

```
CONFIG_CROSS_COMPILE="arm-linux-"
```

so that the kernel would use `arm-linux-gcc` instead of `gcc` to cross compile for the arm architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ln` command is creating a symbolic link; as specified from `/usr/bin/gcc` to a file called `ygcc` in your current directory.  For this link to be useful:

1. `gcc` needs to be at `/usr/bin/gcc`; if it has a different location you'll need to change that part of the command to an appropriate path.
2. When you compile the kernel you need to have the `ygcc` file you have created on your path.  Make sure it is on your `PATH` and/or make the link in a directory which is on your path.